# Thread 1: SIGABRT (Could not cast value of the 'NSError' to 'NSString')

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3

Ok so when I run my app on my iPhone it allows me to enter information in the text fields but crashes when I tap on the 'Sign Up' button.

This is showAlert function in the view controller:

> 2016-12-12 20:24:37.943 Elixr[2013:473247] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.12 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
>   {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Unable to verify secret hash for client 5pmvgst5c9650q4v9dfii8g8h7"}
>   Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x1a7abc0f0) to 'NSString' (0x1a7abc398).
>
> > 2016-12-12 20:24:37.955718 Elixr[2013:472573] Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x1a7abc0f0) to 'NSString' (0x1a7abc398).

This is what the IBAction for the 'Sign Up' button:

```
    @IBAction func SignUpButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let usernameValue = self.Username.text, !usernameValue.isEmpty,
        let passwordValue = self.Password.text, !passwordValue.isEmpty else {
            showAlert(title: "Missing required fields", message: "Please enter a username or password.")
            return
    }

    var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()

    if let emailValue = self.Email.text, !emailValue.isEmpty {
        let email = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
        email?.name = "email"
        email?.value = emailValue
        attributes.append(email!)
    }

    // Sign up the user
    self.pool?.signUp(usernameValue, password: passwordValue, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil).continue ({[weak self] (task: AWSTask  ) -> AnyObject? in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if let error = task.error {

                self?.showAlert(title: "Error", message: error as! String) ---> ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE <---


            } else if let result = task.result   {
                // handle the case where user has to confirm his identity via email / SMS
                if (result.user.confirmedStatus != AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed) {
                    strongSelf.sentTo = result.codeDeliveryDetails?.destination
                    strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpConfirmSegue", sender:sender)
                } else {

                    self?.showAlert(title: "Registration Complete", message: "Registration was successful.")

                    strongSelf.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })
        return nil
    })
```

This is the showAlert function:

```
    func showAlert(title : String, message : String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A general good approach is to handle errors internally and show the user only "user friendly" messages based on what caused that error (eg. We are sorry but it appears.../ please try again.../ enter your password in order to login/ no internet/...)
2. Apple's documentation states the following

> Use the forced form of the type cast operator (as!) only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed. This form of the operator will trigger a runtime error if you try to downcast to an incorrect class type.

3. One property that you might use to show info about the NSError is

> var **localizedDescription**: String A string containing the localized
>   description of the error.

```
showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
```

Comment: Ok that works however now, but how can I add a custom error message instead of using the default message?

Comment: Well, our general approach is to have a method that returns the userfriendly message based on that error (passed as an argument). This is because the error should be treated by code/reason/description and only then, decide the message you want to display to the user. You can even add a general message there for an untreated situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`localizedDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror/1414418-localizeddescription) property of `(NS)Error` to display error message.

```
self?.showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
```